# How to fix the error: "No Next.js version could be detected in your project." when deploying to Vercel with Turborepo and pnpm

Tags: next.js, vercel, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I am trying to deploy the Turborepo [example app](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/tree/main/examples/with-pnpm) to Vercel using instructions from [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos), and getting the error:

```
Error: No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos) says that the build command `npm install --prefix=../..` is only required if using npm workspaces, and doesn't apply when using pnpm or yarn workspaces. Since am using pnpm, I replace `npm install --prefix=../..` with `pnpm i -r` and it worked.